# Potential security flaw using create table like

Tags: security, data-masking, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've discovered an unexpected result while using data masking on tables.  I have a process, running in an elevated role, that loads a table with sensitive data.  Because the ingested data is effectively a complete refresh of the table the process runs as follows:

Table A exists with data masking rules on several columns.

Table B is created using `create transient table B like A copy grants`

Data is loaded and processed in table B.

Table A is updated using `alter table A swap with B`

Table B is dropped.

What happens is table B is created missing the data masking policy applied to the specific columns  where it existed in table A.  When swapped, the prior masking policy on table A is eliminated as it no longer exists on table B.

To resolve this, after creating table B I have to reapply the data masking policy.  Once this is in place, it then gets swapped to table A in the swap operation.

I think this is a flaw for developers not expecting this behavior and could leave information exposed if they do not test their work properly.

My expected behavior is either:

(1) When creating table B like A, table B also includes all data policies on that table, this could be column masking or row level security.

(2) When swapping table B with A, the table being swapped into (A) maintains the data policies on that table.

My preference would be (1).  Perhaps this can be an additional command like

```
create table B 
like A 
copy grants
copy [masking] policies;
```

Is this really a security flaw or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

> Table A is updated using alter table A swap with B
>
> Table B is dropped.Table A is updated using alter table A swap with B
>
> Table B is dropped.

In the first step, it starts with Table A having the masking policy and ends with Table B having it after the swap.

In the second step, the table with the masking policy, Table B is dropped.

The SWAP WITH syntax is equivalent to doing this in one step instead of three:

```
alter TABLE_A    rename to TABLE_TEMP;
alter TABLE_B    rename to TABLE_A;
alter TABLE_TEMP rename to TABLE_B;
```

The SWAP WITH syntax allows this to happen in a single transaction so there's not a momentary instant that the table names are not what they need to be. So you can see when its steps are explicit it's more clear that the table with the masking policy applied to it is dropped in this sequence of steps.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, The real issue is that the create table B like A does not include the data masking that exists on A.  B should also inherit the masking.

I've now raised a support case with Snowflake, so we'll see what they say.

Comment: That's a good point. I checked the docs and it states "Column names, types, defaults, and constraints are copied to the new table". That doesn't explicitly mention masking policy, but I think it's a reasonable expectation for that to be the default behavior.

Comment: @Kerry did anything ever come from that ticket? This definitely feels like an issue to me and Snowflake should at least provide an option to bring the Masking policies applications to the new table.